# How To Give Space Between THe EditText , Not Margin I want to set Padding in Android

Tags: padding, margin

I have to set padding between the EditText Feild, If I set padding it affects HintText not Field. So, How to set the padding,Margin effects but i don't want to use margin.
Suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Erm using what. .Net, winforms, WPF, HTML , Java, Cobol????

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug.. It is just about logic, Which i didn't use.